# Java Source error markers in Common Navigator Explorer

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-jdt

I have a Java Source file inside a Common Navigator explorer Project Tree (Custom Perspective). After building, it has few errors. The errors I can see in the Problems View, but no error display (red X) on the Java File in the explorer. But when I switch to Java Perspective, I can see the error display in the package explorer. How I can shoe the error display in my custom perspective?

Comment: This may be possible if your missing to import some of its libraries